# Access VBA Return 0 in grouping even if there is no match

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2013

I have employees table in access db with days on which they have worked on:

Table A

```
employee_id | date_wrk | Project | Worked
-----------------------------------------
1   10      |01.01.2015|Project1 | 1
2   10      |12.01.2015|Project1 | 0,5
3   10      |01.02.2015|Project1 | 1    
4   10      |01.02.2015|Project2 | 1     
5   10      |04.02.2015|Project2 | 1  
6   12      |05.02.2015|Project2 | 1
```

What i need is Final table with sum of days done by month by projects:

```
employee_id | Month   | Project   | Worked
-----------------------------------------
    10      |January  | Project 1  | 1,5
    10      |February | Project 1  | 1
    10      |February | Project 2  | 2
    10      |March    | Project 1  | 0
```

I group by month(date) with sum of days worked - The problem is I want to display all months jan-dec - the month and 0 if employee doesn't have any day worked in given month for given project..

I tried to build months table with all months listed and right join it but it doesnt help..

Any ideas would be appriciated.

Cheers!
    .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to avoid `right join` because it's needlessly confusing.

Here's an example `left join` approach:

```
select  e.employee_id
,       m.month
,       a.project
,       sum(a.worked)
from    (
        select  distinct employee_id
        from    TableA
        ) e
,       MonthsTable m
left join
        TableA a
on      a.employee_id = m.employee_id
        and month(a.date_wrk) = m.month
group by
        e.employee_id
,       m.month
,       a.project
```

The `cross join` creates a matrix of each employee and each month.  For each employee-month combination in the matrix, it optionally looks up the project hours.

Comment: Thanks Andomar, that would work but I think cross join is not supported by access 2015 db : (

Comment: You're right!  I just Googled that you can simulate a `cross join` with a comma-separated list after `from`... does the updated answer work?

Comment: I tried like this but access returns: Join expression not supported: `SELECT e.employee_id, a.project, m.month, Sum(a.[worked]) 
from 
(select distinct  
 EmployeeID from TableA
) e ,Months m
left join TableA a
on Month(a.date_wrk) = m.month
and a.employee_id = m.employee_id
group by e.employee_id,  a.project, m.month`

Answer (score 1):

Ok I did it basing on Andomar suggestion - but as  Access is not fond of sub-queries and cross join I created additional table based on :

```
select  distinct employee_id,months.month
from TableA,months
```

which give me a cross join table which then I linked to tableA.

Cheers!

Comment: Nice one, the zen of Access goes in strange paths, hehe